# Fill a DTO with two findAll() of two different types in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, mapping, dto

I have two collections of different types. The collection are returned by two servicices, that return two findAll() in two repositories.

I want to combine the two collection in a DTO. My DTO is just a combination of all the collections models variables.

This is my code. I tryed a lot of technique, this is one of them. I want to return a CombinationModel collection

```
            List<OneModel> listOne = oneService.oneEndPoint(); // findAll()
            List<TwoModel> listTwo = twoService.twoEndPoint(); // findAll()

            List<ConbinationModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.addAll(listOne);
            list.addAll(listTwo);
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do here. Do you want to map both OneModel and TwoModel to an object of type CombinationModel? If yes why don't you create two constructors in your CombinationModel class like fromOneModel(OneModel model) returning a CombinationModel? And same for TwoModel?

Comment: Yes this is what I'm trying to do, I will try to ad the constructors

Comment: Or a single constructor with two parameters. Or a mapper utility method that instantiates a new combiantion object and initializes it using the corresponding getters from the two model objects and the setters of the combination object. The possibilities are many.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options here. One could be creating two static constructors in your `ConbinationModel` class like:

```
public static ConbinationModel fromOneModel(OneModel model) {
    final ConbinationModel conbinationModel = new ConbinationModel();
    conbinationModel.setField(model.getField());
    // set other fields
    return conbinationModel;
}
```

```
public static ConbinationModel fromTwoModel(TwoModel model) {
    final ConbinationModel conbinationModel = new ConbinationModel();
    conbinationModel.setField(model.getField());
    // set other fields
    return conbinationModel;
}
```

And then you could stream over your lists:

```
List<ConbinationModel> fromListOne = listOne.stream()
    .map(ConbinationModel::fromOneModel)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
List<ConbinationModel> fromListTwo = listTwo.stream()
    .map(ConbinationModel::fromTwoModel)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```